# cant set up the nginx server (port forwarding)

Tags: python, django, nginx, linksys

i'm using django and nginx and gunicorn to setup my application.

When i do port forwarding 80---->80 and go to my ip it works.
when i use the "german god" anonymity program, then it does not respond.
So i mean that, when I go to my own ip from my computer, then the program works fine.

When I do the same from outside, then I have no response. I thought that my internet service provider blocks port 80.

What I tried to do is to setup port forwarding for 8001 ----> 80 but still does not work.

Thats the nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/www/shop/00/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/shop/00/error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/shop/00/static/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

Thats the nginx config file.

```
bind = u"127.0.0.1:8888"
logfile = u"/var/www/shop/00/gunicorn.log"
workers = 3
```

and my port forwarding is like so:
[image]

Thanks in advance.